# Mysql Query out multiple result sets? (sql there's here)

Tags: mysql

Sql:

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    example_table tb
WHERE
    ID = 
        (SELECT
            FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(1)) rand
        FROM
            example_table tb
        limit 1)
```

Problem: There are often multiple result sets?

[image]

Comment: Select `ID` column along with `nickname` and check if all the records have same `ID`.

Comment: Id ensure that the primary key is unique

Comment: What is your goal? Is it something like you want to get a random nickname?

Comment: To get the name of a random person, I've actually solved the requirement problem, but this SQL makes me confused!

Answer (score 0):

Solution：

```
 SELECT
    name
FROM
    example_table tb,
    (SELECT
        FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(1)) rand
    FROM
        example_table ) e_tb
WHERE
    ID = e_tb.rand
```

What is the difference between two sentences?